# Ionic add platform ios showing phonegap-plugin-push error on mac OS Sierra

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi when i tried to platform add ios showing the following error, 
Adding ios project...

Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.leniko.fuel-buddy
    Name: Fuel Buddy
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.4.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-app-version" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-apprate" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-dialogs@1.3.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-globalization@1.0.4" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-globalization" for ios
Cross-platform AppRate plugin for Cordova / PhoneGap
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.1.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for ios
Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
Plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.1.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios.

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugins README to see if you application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

```
  "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"
```

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.

Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on ios.
Plugin "cordova-plugin-globalization" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-toast" for ios
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
Error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ env        Display pod environment
+ init       Generate a Podfile for the current directory
+ install    Install project dependencies according to versions from a
             Podfile.lock
+ ipc        Inter-process communication
+ lib        Develop pods
+ list       List pods
+ outdated   Show outdated project dependencies
+ repo       Manage spec-repositories
+ setup      Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec       Manage pod specs
+ update     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--silent     Show nothing
--version    Show the version of the tool
--verbose    Show more debugging information
--no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
--help       Show help banner of specified command
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I had installed cocoapods and run the above command with sudo and without sudo.

Comment: Did you run `pod setup` after installing `cocoapods`?

Comment: yes i have done it.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem by changing the plugin phonegap-push with Firebase plugin and now its working fine in android as well as IOS. Please go with the cordova-firebase plugin version 1.22.